# Computer lagging badly on all operating systems

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

I've been having the longest battle with a computer I assembled myself years ago.

At the time I wasn't using it so I installed windows 8.1 (another battle in itself) and gave the computer to my brother. It has suffered from chronic lag ever since.

The computer takes excessively long to boot the operating system, open applications, or even just to respond to clicks. It's so bad as to be unusable. I have tried this computer with Windows 7 and various flavours of Linux and they all suffer from the same lag immediately after a clean install.

I eventually suspected I may have faulty hardware but checking online I can't find any symptoms of hardware failure. I have noticed that Live CDs run just fine so I thought the HDD may have slow read/write speeds, so I used hdparm to run some tests. These are the HDD results from my brothers computer:

```
user@users-desktop:~$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

   /dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   25104 MB in  2.00 seconds = 12563.45 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  40 MB in  6.05 seconds =   6.61 MB/sec
user@users-desktop:~$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   24968 MB in  2.00 seconds = 12495.77 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  40 MB in  5.21 seconds =   7.68 MB/sec
user@users-desktop:~$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   25732 MB in  2.00 seconds = 12878.63 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  40 MB in  4.42 seconds =   9.06 MB/sec
```

Comparing these results against a HDD speed calculator online I thought this was way too slow to not be faulty. However I did the same test on my own personal computer which doesn’t suffer from lag and the results were similar.

To sum up, this computer suffers from lag after a clean install no matter what operating system is running. I get no other apparent errors. I believe the hardware may be faulty but I do not know how to test it or what may be at fault.

All the hardware was new when I bought it several years ago and other than installing different operating systems, it hasn't been put under serious load.

I can't remember the computers specs other than it having a Intel i5, 1TB HDD, Asus GTX 640, 8GB RAM.

I've tried everything I can with this computer so any help would be great. The computer is also in a different city from me, so it will be some time before I can try anything else.

Comment: Other things to find out: how busy is the computer doing other things? Start up `top` and keep an eye on it while you press buttons and start programs. Is there any heavy swapping? You haven't told us about your memory. How much is it and is it all there, i.e. no faulty chips?

Comment: You get the memory information with the command `free`. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/607544/edit) your question to provide the output. Btw, my maybe 7 years old 60GB laptop HDD has 10x slower cache reading times and 5-6x faster disk reading times than your machine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It has 8GB of RAM in a single stick. I presume it is working ok, but I haven't run any tests. The computer is in another city at the moment, so it will be some time before I can get back to it.

Comment: Try this to check your speed and report back: `dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=512 count=1000000` for write and `dd if=file of=/dev/null` for read, then `rm file` to delete the temporary file, your speed reports are *way* too slow

Comment: Or better, chain everything into a single command: `dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=512 count=1000000 && dd if=file of=/dev/null && rm file`

Comment: Sorry, you need `iflag=nocache` for the read test: `dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=512 count=1000000 && dd if=file of=/dev/null iflag=nocache && rm file`